# Why does the Xcode "Page-Based Application" project template have a PageController?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I'm learning page controllers and have created a blank app using the Page-Based Application template. By default it creates 12 month pages that you can scroll left to right.

On the storyboard there is a Page View Controller Scene with a Page View Controller. However, in the code, there are commands to create this controller programmatically in the root controller. i.e.

```
var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
    self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

    let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
    let viewControllers = [startingViewController]
    self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })

    self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)

    // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
    var pageViewRect = self.view.bounds
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        pageViewRect = pageViewRect.insetBy(dx: 40.0, dy: 40.0)
    }
    self.pageViewController!.view.frame = pageViewRect

    self.pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

In fact, if I delete the Page View Controller from the storyboard, the app works just as before.

I am trying to understand why this would be on the storyboard when it does not appear to be used. Also, are the good reasons to create a Page View Controller programmatically rather than using the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Inside storyboard You have a standard `UIViewController` subclass, not `UIPageViewController`. Your `UIPageViewController` is created in code, and then added as a subview to this RootViewController. RootViewController displays `UIPageViewController` and act as its delegate. I don't think this will work correctly if you delete anything from the storyboard, are you sure about this? There is not instance of `UIPageViewController` in storyboard.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. I must have added that to the storyboard myself. I'll check more carefully in future before asking :)